# C++ MultiThread Worker based approach

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, worker

I am looking to develop a multi-threaded worker based sub-application. I was going through approaches on various site and suddenly tumbled onto a wiki page.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern

> When implementing this pattern, the programmer should ensure
>   thread-safety  of the queue. In Java, you can synchronize the relevant
>   method using the  synchronized keyword. This will bind the block
>   modified with synchronized  into one atomic structure, therefore
>   forcing any threads using the  associated resource to wait until there
>   are no threads using the resource.(  I hope this is achievable by
>   applying mutex lock in c++)  As a drawback to  this method,
>   synchronization is rather expensive. You can also create an  object
>   that holds a list of all the jobs in a queue, which could be a 
>   singleton.

What i want to understand is how a singleton object containing list of all Jobs would help me more than synchronizing the queue. And how will they be exactly different ?

P.S: I know few of you might question the source of my content ( wiki here) but still , i would like to know more about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Edited a bit . And this is my prine question :- How a singleton object containing list of all Jobs would help me more than synchronizing the queue. And how will they be exactly different ?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the article, it isn't claiming that a list of jobs in a queue is an alternative to synchronization, you will have to synchronize access to any data used by multiple threads regardless.  Is there anything we could help you understand in more detail?

Comment: So Does this mean that the only difference here is that synchronization in itself a more expensive call , but when achieved  via a singleton object storing list of Jobs would be a quicker approach ?

Comment: You will have to synchronize access to the job queue regardless of whether or not you use a singleton to store the queue.  I don't know why the article says _You can also create an object that..._, but it is irrelevant to the thread pool pattern.  The basic idea is that you have a queue of jobs and a pool of threads.  Each time a thread is free, it pulls the next job out of the queue to execute.  But it is important that multiple threads don't try to get the next job at the same time, you have to synchronize access to the queue so this doesn't happen.

Comment: I have to go but I will check back later to see if I can help you figure things out.

Comment: You misread the article. Singleton will not help you to have your work queue synchronized, it is a merely a holder for your queue - you see, it has to be somewhere, so article suggest it could be in a singleton. For the record, I whole-heartedly disagree with this. Queues SHOULD NOT be put in a singleton.

Comment: Also even singletons are not thread safe , but that i guess c++11 provides an esy way to make it a thread safe right ? I am exactly not using c++11 here though.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to "reinvent the wheel" instead of just using industry-standard approaches like [tbb](/questions/tagged/tbb) or [ppl](/questions/tagged/ppl) (which are specifically target C++ applications)? Both of them are based upon a work-stealing scheduler which scales well (much better than a shared queue) in both directions, enables nested parallelism, and thus solves composability issues which are inevitable when you are inventing your own thread pool or using existing ones with the fixed number of worker threads (like in [openmp](/questions/tagged/openmp)).

Comment: Not everybody uses intel, and even less people use MSVC.

Comment: TBB is open-source and portable library, use it with ARM if you want to.

Comment: @SergeyA, one example of TBB portability is that it is used in mobile phone applications through OpenCV, and it's usually non-intel HW.

Comment: How about Power? How about SPARC? ;)

Comment: @SergeyA TBB is ported to Power by the community. Not sure about SPARC, does anyone use it? :) TBB is certainly open to accept any new ports

Comment: SPARC is heavily used to the environment I am very familiar with.

Comment: ok, here is the TBB port for SPARC https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-threading-building-blocks/topic/298085

Comment: yes , what i am looking for is a open source reliable library , which provides this functionality . But how reliable is TBB and do we have a proper documentation for the same. ?

Comment: @Invictus, TBB is used in in production in many mature applications. You can find [documentation here](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/index.htm).